# How many 4 digit pins on set {0-9}

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

A password can be any 4 digit {0...9}.

1.)How many possible passwords are there?

for this I did $10^4 = 10,000$

2.) How many possible passwords with no repeated digits?

$10*9*8*7 = 5040$

3.) How many possible passwords are there with repeated digits?

For this do I just subtract 10,000-5040?

Edit: typos. Thanks everyone.

Comment: I think you mean 1 should be $10^{4}$..

Comment: You are correct.  Repeated digits and no repeated digits are mutually exclusive and span the entire set of passwords so what you did works.

Comment: Typo. $10^4$. Yes. Pins either have repeated digits or they don't. So REPEAT +NON =ALL so REPEAT = ALL - NON. That's ligical, isn't it? (And yes, other than the typi, you did 1 and 2 perfectly correctly.)

Answer (score 2):

community wiki answer so the question can be closed

Your solutions to the first two questions are correct.

Yes, to find the number of passwords with repeated digits, you subtract the number of passwords with no repeated digits from the total, so there are $10000 - 5040 = 4960$, as you found.

Answer (score 0):

For question 2, if you don't consider $0$ as a possible digit for the first number (because then it would be a 3 digit number, rather than a 4 digit number), then the answer is $9*9*8*7 = 4536$.